# Where can BangPatterns appear

Tags: haskell, ghc, strictness

From [GHC user guide](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/7.8.4/docs/html/users_guide/bang-patterns.html) it seems like most `Pat` can be `PBangPat`, but there are a few exceptions. e.g. top-level bangs in a module (like `!main`) aren't allowed <s>and `x : !xs` fails to parse</s> `x : (!xs) parses` thanks @chi. What is the formal specification about where the bangs can be added? I've looked into some chapters of the user guide and the Report but found nothing.

Comment: Good question, though in doubt it's probably best not to use BangPatterns at all but good old `seq`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no accepted formal specification for BangPatterns since they are not a part of any Haskell Report. The closest thing we have to a specification is the User's Guide along with the haskell-prime proposal it links to.

Both of those sources explicitly mention that a bang pattern is not allowed at the top level of a module.

As for `x : !xs`, the User's Guide has this to say about the syntax of bang patterns:

> We add a single new production to the syntax of patterns:
>
> ```
> pat  ::= !pat
> ```

It should be read in conjunction with the Haskell 2010 Report:

> ```
> pat  ::= lpat qconop pat
>        | lpat
>
> lpat ::= apat
>        | - (integer | float)
>        | gcon apat_1 ... apat_k
>
> apat ::= var [ @ apat]
>        | ...
>        | ( pat )
>        | ...
> ```

According to these rules `x : !xs` actually should parse (since `!xs` is a `pat`, the whole thing is `lpat qconop pat`). So either the User's Guide (and the haskell-prime proposal) is wrong or GHC is wrong on this point.

I believe that in practice the syntax accepted by GHC is "anything that looks like a valid expression" including interpreting `(!x)` as a section of the operator `!`. For example `(! Just x)` is accepted as a pattern but `(! ! x)` is not.

Comment: Actually [the relevant section of the User's Guide](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/bang-patterns.html#bang-patterns-sem) is so old that it links to the *Haskell 98* report, and the BNF grammar at that time treated precedence differently. [For patterns in particular](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/exps.html#sect3.17.1), adding `pat  ::= !pat` means to add it at the *lowest precedence*.

Comment: Although disturbingly, by this reading `(! ! x)` *should* work but doesn't.

Comment: @ØrjanJohansen, oh good point. I didn't try following the links to the Report since I already had the 2010 Report open in another tab. That does make the description closer to reality, though as you say still not quite the same.

Comment: See also https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/1087 and https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/10732.